# Give the option in admin to change custom module route on frontend

Tags: magento2, routing

Say on frontend your main module page is `www.website/test/`

etc/frontend/routes.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Vendor_Name" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In the admin I've built a list of settings. Among those I would like to give the option to change "test" into something else.

So, depending on client's needs, he can change that link.

How would I go about doing that? Just some general hints would be really helpfull.

Thanks!

Comment: This should help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100796/magento2-adding-dynamic-route-name

Comment: What about creating URL rewrites on the fly ? That could be an easy to implement solution