# Magento 2 custom url rewrite ignores query string

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, url-rewrite

I am migrating a store from an old custom commerce system to Magento 2. I am trying to add URL rewrites into Magento 2 using the Marketing -> Url Rewrite tool.

The old URLs for the store look like this:

`store/detail/x.php?id=123`

I can enter that into the Request Path just fine, but anything with a `?` in it never actually forwards to the Target Path. If I remove the `?`, it redirects fine.. but obviously that is not a valid URL.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento 2 reads parameters in the following format:
`somepage/param/param_value/`

It ignores the question mark. In your situation you have 2 options to go:

1) Manage this by using the rewrite rules of the webserver.

For more information on this, please check:

- Nginx - https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- Apache - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

2) Write your custom router for processing URLs

Please see my example on how to do this there: [Configure front name in admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246558/configure-front-name-in-admin-panel/246564#246564)

Comment: I was trying to avoid this route, but it looks easier to put them in nginx than it does to create a new url processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module which works the same as a htaccess rewrite rule. After two days trying to get htaccess rewrite to work I found this works perfectly for Magento 2.4: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158811/109113