# Configure front name in admin panel

Tags: magento2

I need to create input on

> store->configuration

that set front name to module. How can I do it ? Sorry, but I don’t know how I can start.

For example: *I input :**”test”**, and URL is **mysite.loc/test**. Controller index.php in index directory*

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to start reading about custom routers. I believe, for implementing this feature you need to create your own router which will be processing the query in the URL, then forward to the page (controller) you need.

Steps to proceed with your custom router:

1. Read DevDocs regarding routers / custom router:
   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#custom-routers
2. Investigate the example of custom router implementation for CMS Pages:

`vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="cms" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

`vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Router.php`

3. Following the examples above, you'll be able to impelement your own router for your needs.