# 302 Redirects for a specific store view

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, router

I have a site with 2 store views.

One of the views (lets call it store view X), should be accessible to only certain users, and parts of the store should be restricted when this store view is enabled.

For example, when a logged in user is of the correct customer group and X is enabled, i don't want them to access /wishlist, or customer/account, i want those pages to be redirected to the homepage.

What i've tried is to add redirects specific to store view X of type 302,

i.e. request path - wishlist, target path - ../, type 302

I've then tried reindexing and navigating to the page wishlist, only to find the redirect doesn't work. That route doesn't even hit Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router match() ln 60.

how can i redirect pages such as this for a specific store view, and can someone explain why the Router isn't being hit?

Thanks,

Sophie

Comment: Link to github ticket https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8718#issuecomment-283126284

Comment: Do you have fullpage cache enabled ?

Comment: I've tried with the cache enabled and disabled. The redirect works on some pages but not others so i'm not sure the cache is the issue.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's the Magento\Framework\App\FrontController.php dispatch() matching a custom router before the url redirect router as it loops through the router list. How do I get it to match against the url redirect router before all others though?

Comment: Indeed the router is sorted : Base Router → CMS Router → UrlRewrite Router → Default Router

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100796/magento2-adding-dynamic-route-name explain you how to create a new router, you can also change the router sort order at your own risk. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/routing.html

Comment: So for all the areas where i need to apply a redirect, such as wishlist, customer/account (magento core modules), i need to create a custom router that duplicates the logic of the urlRewrite router? i.e. logic to find the redirect depending on the store_id. I feel like it should be made clearer that redirects added through the admin won't necessarily work given this specific scenario. Am i missing something, surely if you're adding a custom redirect in the admin it should just work regardless?

Comment: You may have a look of this Force Login Module : https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login

Answer (score 0):

You can add an observer to the `controller_action_predispatch` event in order to add your own logic of restriction.

**events.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="custom_restrict" instance="Vendor\Restriction\Observer\CustomRestrict" />
</event>
```

**CustomRestrict.php**

```
/**
 * Implement some restriction
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $controller \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action */
    $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

    $this->restrictor->restrict(
        $observer->getEvent()->getRequest(),
        $this->response,
    );
}
```

Where `$this->restrictor` is your restriction class model with your logic.

But you may encounter problems if you use Varnish or other cache system.