# Using Reserved Words in Magento 2 URLs

Tags: magento2, php, controllers, routing

Is it possible to create a module in Magento 2, using standard routing, that responds to a URL in the form of

```
http://magento.example.com/namespace_module/return/index
```

That is -- a URL where the *second* parameter is a PHP reserved keyword.  The problem with the above is is create a PHP controller class name that's

```
Namespace\Module\Controller\Return\Index
```

and having `Return` in the namespace is illegal PHP.  I know if the URL's final parameter (traditionally called the action) was a reserved keyword

```
http://magento.example.com/namespace_module/foo/return
```

that Magento would let me create a controller class named

```
Namespace\Module\Controller\Foo\ReturnAction
```

However, this does not work for the second parameter.

Is there a way to do this using standard Magento 2 routing techniques?

If not, is there a generally considered best practice for injecting a custom router object to get this behavior, or some other technique that would let me work around this? (an `after` plugin on `Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up adding a plugin for `Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList`

```
<!-- File: app/code/Package/Namespace/etc/di.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList">
        <plugin name="package_module_magento_framework_app_router_actionlist" type="Package\Module\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and then fiddled with the `$namespace` parameter of the `get` method

```
#File: app/code/Package/Module/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php
public function beforeGet($subject, $module, $area, $namespace, $action)
{
    if($namespace === 'return')
    {
        $namespace = 'returnaction';
    }
    return [$module, $area, $namespace, $action];
}
```

This gave me a class name of

```
Package\Module\Controller\ReturnAction\Index
```

Not sure how good an idea this is, so buyer beware, etc.

Comment: This looks nice and easy. Specially because it can be extended to all php reserved words in the same way the action names are mapped to action classes. An alternative would be to create a [custom router](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/100796/146) but this requires way more code.

Comment: Only a couple comments:

1) This will change the namespace for any module that tries to use the 'return' controller. Unless you're intentionally creating a 'catchall' it might be best to check the $module parameter to match your own module.

2) If we're going to try to preserve naming parity, the returned $namespace should probably be 'returnController' - which would then search for the ReturnController namespace/filepath. This would then load `\Namespace\Module\Controller\ReturnController\Index` - which is more accurate.